# CSS GRID: How to take the whole row in a random position

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm getting crazy about an issue, very simple, but which I can't find a solution.

So, I have a grid with 2 columns and infinite rows:

I'd need to show an ADV 100% in a whole row but I don't know when and where the ADV will be fired.
It can be fired after 6 elements or after 10, so I can't use "span" grid position.

How can I do that?

```css
.grid { display: grid; grid-template-columns: 50% 50%; background-color:#f2f2f2; }
.grid > div { background-color:#999; margin:12px; text-align:center; padding:12px; }
.grid .whole_adv { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div> <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div> <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div> <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div> <div>8</div>
  <div class="whole_adv">100%</div>
  <div>9</div> <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div> <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div> <div>14</div>
  <div class="whole_adv">100%</div>
  <div>15</div> <div>16</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: u need to use grid inside the grid , and give bg-color to the parent grid row

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more please? Why you can't use `grid-column: 1 / span 2;`?

Comment: @Jax-p for some reason now it works. It was the first thing that I tried and didn't work. I don't why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element to span an entire row, just set the `grid-column` property to `1 / span 2`:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.grid>div {
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
}

.grid .whole_adv {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div class="whole_adv">100%</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div class="whole_adv">100%</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
</div>
```

[grid-column - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column)
[A Complete Guide to Grid - CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Thank you Richard. Indeed it works properly. Thanks a lot!